# send_keys does not work with Selenium Python on Google Flights

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath

Trying to webscrape Google Flights https://www.google.com/travel/flights,  but is stuck on an early problem, I cant do `send_keys()` to the input.

```
fly_from = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
"//*[@id='i6']/div[4]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/input")

fly_from.send_keys("lax")
```

This does not work. I have tried with multiple combinations with click(), clear() and time.sleep(). It worked one time for about two tries, then it stopped working again.

Comment: can you show me browser dom structure

Comment: I know I am finding the right input because if I do click() it will be clicked. the URL is https://www.google.com/travel/flights and I am trying to fill the inputs at the landingpage

Comment: i checked pass. it was correct

Comment: what is the difference between what you wrote and what was in my code?

Comment: did you insert time sleep

Comment: I have tried it in multiple combinations with no progress. What sometimes happens aswell is it will send only the first character in my word but not the rest of the word. That happens when i have my code as i have it above

Comment: try it with inserting time sleep, later if you can't, send your project to me.

Comment: I often find some input boxes need a click (to set focus) before a send key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the page you've linked, I think the problem is that a new element appears covering up the first element you've identified, as soon as you've typed or clicked in the first element. So if you click on the element you identified, define the new element, then `send_keys()` it works for me. Like this:

```
fly_from = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
"//*[@id='i6']/div[4]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/input")
fly_from.click()
fly_from_text = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="i6"]/div[6]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/input')
fly_from_text.send_keys("lax")
```

Also, I'll just point out the variable name `fly_from` doesn't seem to make sense because this field is the destination field.

Comment: I know your locators were taken from and then "inspired by" OP's locators but they are pretty brittle. I would use the CSS selector, `"input[placeholder='Where to?']"`, for the click and then the CSS selector, `"input[aria-label='Where to?']"`, for the send keys. I like my locators to be at least near readable whenever possible.

Answer (score 1):

I see it is already answered, but such kind of locator won't last long.

I am posting a much better version utilising explicit waits and much more robust locators.

About locators: `.`- class name, `>` - direct child.
All details are in the comments to the code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/snap/bin/chromium.chromedriver')
driver.get('https://www.google.com/travel/flights')
assert "Google Flights" in driver.title
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".e5F5td.BGeFcf .V00Bye.ESCxub.KckZb>input[class='II2One j0Ppje zmMKJ LbIaRd']")))  # waiting for autocompleted field
field = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".e5F5td.BGeFcf .V00Bye.ESCxub.KckZb>input[class='II2One j0Ppje zmMKJ LbIaRd']")  # finding autocompleted field
field.clear()  # clearing autocompleted field
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".BGeFcf .V00Bye.ESCxub.KckZb>input")))
click_input = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".BGeFcf .V00Bye.ESCxub.KckZb>input")
click_input.click()  # clicking the field for a new input becoming interactible 
fly_from = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[aria-label='Where from?']")
city = "Moscow"
fly_from.send_keys("Moscow")  # making search
```

While debugging, I was also trying making input with small delays, like below, but this was not the issue:

```
city = "Moscow"
for char in city:
    fly_from.send_keys(char)
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

The real issue is changing input locator.

Comment: While I'm not going to defend my locators, things like `.e5F5td.BGeFcf .V00Bye.ESCxub.KckZb>input[class='II2One j0Ppje zmMKJ LbIaRd']` sure don't look stable to me either.

Comment: This is Google and their class names are stable.

Comment: `.e5F5td.BGeFcf .V00Bye.ESCxub.KckZb>input[class='II2One j0Ppje zmMKJ LbIaRd']` this has some serious issue @vitaliis, if you reload or launch the script next time it will probably not work.

Comment: OK, I'm not familiar with Google's CSS. Maybe this is better.

Comment: It works for me too, maybe it is stable over time, if you have experience with such I defer to you @vitaliis

Comment: OK, I just wanted to improve the suggestions.

Comment: @vitaliis : I'm done for today.. would run your code tomorrow and let you know.

Comment: Those classes look obfuscated to me and my guess is that next time they ship X, they will change again. It may not be tomorrow... but maybe next week or whenever. See my comment under C. Peck's answer for what I think are much better, more readable and less brittle, locators.

Comment: @JeffC You are right. Your locators are also good, They also have some probability to be changed after a next few sprints. Mine can be reduced, but it would require some more testing.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably remove that absolute xpath and can use the relative xpath given below :

```
//input[@role='combobox' and @aria-expanded='false'][not(@placeholder ='Where to?')]
```

**Code :**

```
fly_from = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
"//input[@role='combobox' and @aria-expanded='false'][not(@placeholder ='Where to?')]")

fly_from.send_keys("lax")
```

Comment: First of all I can't find any element with that selector... I'm assuming you can. But even if the selector works, does this actually solve the question?

Comment: @C.Peck : I have changed the locator, I did not see all the comment at first. was clicking first and sending correct solution ?

Comment: Yeah there's something a little goofy/complicated with that field on google. I wouldn't personally use those xpaths in my answer, but it works.